# How to convert a DateTimeOffset to another time zone

Tags: .net, date, timezone

Assuming `source` is an arbitrary `DateTimeOffset`, I want to assign a variable `dest` (also of type `DateTimeOffset`) to the same moment in time in New York, with the appropriate offset.  The following code seems to do that:

```
var utcSource = source.ToUniversalTime();
var destZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var destDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcSource.DateTime, destZone);
var destZoneOffset = destZone.GetUtcOffset(destDateTime);
var dest = new DateTimeOffset(destDateTime, destZoneOffset);
```

My question: Is there a simpler way?  This seems like a lot of code for a very common requirement, especially since `DateTimeOffset` is preferred to `DateTime` for most use cases. (I realize that the code would be simpler if I just used `DateTime`.)

Comment: You may look at [`ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId_System_DateTimeOffset_System_String_) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pavel pointed out in the question's comments, you can do this in one line as follows:

```
DateTimeOffset dest = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(source, "Eastern Standard Time");
```

Or if you've already got a `TimeZoneInfo` object for the destination, then do this:

```
DateTimeOffset dest = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(source, destZone);
```

Of course, you can use `var` if you prefer.

A couple of points:

- Be careful that `source` is indeed a `DateTimeOffset`.  If it's actually a `DateTime`, then the `.Kind` property of the source value will affect the operation in ways that may not be obvious.  The docs for each conversion method contain a table that describes this behavior, which is *not* the same for each method.
- The `.DateTime` property of a `DateTimeOffset` returns a `DateTime` with the `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` kind.  With `ConvertTimeFromUtc` that will be treated as UTC, but if you had inadvertantly used `ConvertTime` - then unspecified would be treated as *local* time.  So be careful there.
- Also be aware that there is a one-way implicit cast from `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset`, in which the `.Kind` is considered.  This can be an issue if you did the conversion using `DateTime`, but then assigned the result to a `DateTimeOffset`.  You're not here, but it's another common error to watch out for.

Comment: Thanks... summary is... avoid `DateTime`!

Comment: Actually - no.  That's a common reaction, but there are many valid use cases for `DateTime` that `DateTimeOffset` doesn't work well with.  In particular, `DateTimeOffset` is *always* representing a specific point in time, but sometimes you really do need it to be "unspecified".  Here's a good overview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime